# Dynamically insert rows

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I want to ask couple of Qs.

1.
Code below dynamically add new rows before the cell that contain "7000"

Code works but it is not very efficient. It slows down where I used For Next loop to insert new rows. Is there better way to insert rows dynamically before cell that contain "7000".

```
Sub PLFinalReport()

Dim XCount As Integer
Dim YCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

JobsPivot.Activate

XCount = JobsPivot.Range("H3", Range("H3").End(xlDown)).Count

PLJob.Activate

Range("G6", Range("G6").End(xlDown)).Find("7000").Select

YCount = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlUp)).Count - 2

For i = 1 To (XCount - YCount)
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
Next i

JobsPivot.Activate

JobsPivot.Range("H3", Range("H3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
PLJob.Range("G6").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

2. Also I want to copy the forumulas from cell B444 to F44 and paste them all the way down to the last row containing formulas. Same way as we do in the excel with fill handle.

Thanks

Comment: Is `JobsPivot` a pivot table?

Comment: 1. B444 to F44? 2. Collect a union of 7000 cells and use offset.resize.insert.

Comment: No, it's a VBA worksheet name.

Comment: sorry my mistake ... B444 to F444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
Sub PLFinalReport()
    ' 13 Feb 2018

    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set SourceRange = JobsPivot.Range("H3")
    With SourceRange
        C = .End(xlToRight).Column - .Column + 1
        Set SourceRange = .Resize((.End(xlDown).Row - .Row + 1), C)
    End With

    C = 7                                           ' Column G
    With PLJob
        R = MatchRow("7000", .Cells(6, C))          ' = G6
        If R Then
            Set TargetRange = Range(.Cells(R, C), .Cells((R + SourceRange.Rows.Count - 1), C))
            TargetRange.Rows.EntireRow.Insert
            SourceRange.Copy .Cells(R, "H")         ' column H
        Else
            ' "7000" wasn't found
        End If
    End With


    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub

Private Function MatchRow(ByVal Crit As Variant, _
                          ByVal StartCell As Range) As Long
    ' 13 Feb 2018

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rl As Long
    Dim Fnd As Range

    With StartCell.Worksheet
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row        ' find last used row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(StartCell.Row, StartCell.Column), _
                        .Cells(Rl, StartCell.Column))
    End With

    With Rng
        Set Fnd = .Find(What:=Crit, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    MatchRow = Fnd.Row
End Function
```

I was more careful with the `Find` function because there are many reasons why the item might not be found causing an "unexplained" crash. One of the reasons is that Excel remembers most of the settings of your last use of `Find`. If your code doesn't make clear which settings to use you may not always get the same result with the same code. Consider the setting of the `LookAt` property in this regard.

I didn't look into your second question because - in essence - it is another question.

Comment: Thanks mate for your time to answer my Q. Really appreciate it. I am new on the forum so I was't aware that I can only ask one Q at a time. I will post the second Q separately.

Comment: Since you are new let me point out the importance of selecting an answer. You see, your question will remain in this forum's data for a long time. Other visitors who have similar problems may find it and may find the answers helpful. That is where your input is important! Among the answers you receive you should select the one which is the most helpful - as a beacon to other seekers of help and advice. It's your responsibility to make sure it is complete and free from mistakes after testing. Selecting an answer is also a way of saying thank you to the author who gains reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in one statement like:

```
Range("G6", Range("G6").End(xlDown)).Find("7000").Resize(XCount - YCount).EntireRow.Insert
```

as for your second question you can use something like follows (explanations in comments, so you can adjust it to your needs):

```
With PLJob 'reference PLJob
    With .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'reference its columns A and B cells from row 2 down to column A last not empty one
        .Formula = .Resize(1).Formula 'copy/paste formulas
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Can you please help me with my second Q

Comment: be more specific with your second Q

Comment: I want to drag down formulas to the last row used e.g there are some formulas in cell A1 and B1. Same formulas in cells A4 and B4. I want to drag down formulas in cell A1 and B1 to autofill rows 2 and 3.

Comment: @Ali, see edited answer. if it solves your questions then please mark it as accepted. thank you